# Open state of all nodes in Flex Tree

Tags: apache-flex

I need the Flex tree control by default open... where all nodes are visible.

```
theTree.openItems = xmlListColl..node;
```

This is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<root>
<module>
<node>
<node>
</module>
</root>
```

Comment: can you give an example of your XML?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
  tree.dataProvider = event.xml; // where event.xml is type XML
  callLater( tree.expandChildrenOf, [ tree.dataProvider[0], true]);
```

The trick is [0]

Answer (score 2):

```
MyTree.expandChildrenOf(myTreeDataProvider, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the open state, I mean to remove the collapsed state, you have to stop the propagation of the TreeEvent.ITEM_OPENING:

```
    private function onTreeOpeningHandler(argEvent:TreeEvent):void
    {
        argEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's would be better with a test to know if it's opening or not :

```
private function onTreeOpeningHandler(event:TreeEvent):void {
    if (event.opening) {
         return;
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

so you stop the closing, and not the openning :p